# Why coredump does not generate for my C application

Tags: c, debugging

I am running ubuntu 14.04. I ran

```
$ulimit -c unlimited
```

The core dump is enabled and I can generate "core" file in one of my C application directories when I trigger a coredump. During the coredump, I can see the following in shell:

```
 21876 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | ./stack6
```

However, I trigger core dump for another C application in a different directory, but it does not generate "core" files. The message I see during coredump for this application is:

```
 21056 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | ./stackN
```

I am pretty sure it is not a problem of directory permission. Why my second application does not generate the "core" file?

UPDATE 1:
It is probably easy to describe the reason for the core dump instead of posting the code for our discussion.

The code looks like this:

```
static char buf[100];

int main() {
  while (1) {
  // get stdin and copy to buf, we maintain an index so that new inputs will be concatenated with the old one in the buffer.
  }
}
```

The core dump is trigger by giving a large input from stdin. So far, it always dump if I just compile using the second method. I would suspect it is the way the binary is built that causes the coredump issue.

Comment: Post the code that causes the core dump

Comment: The section you have commented out is relevant.  Show the *whole code*.

Comment: code is a large...And I cannot change the code (meaning i cannot tweak it to generate a coredump). Is there any other way to debug this program besides using coredump (note that I do prefer to  rebuild the crash state like what coredump offers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core is getting dumped in the current-working-directory and that may be a different directory from where you started the program.

The program can itself change the current-working-directory -- [chdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) -- and your program may be doing that -- and you may just be looking in the wrong directory

The way you compile the program has no relevance to whther it will generate a core or not, other than the memory layout may be altered so that segfault or whatever is triggering the core may no longer happen

Comment: actually, I made a mistake. You are right, the way i compile does not matter

Comment: hi, i find out the problem. You are totally right. There is a chdir in the code and the core file is right within the targeted directory...

Answer (score 0):

[Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When do something you're not supposed to, such as write outside of memory bounds, anything can happen.  It can core dump, it can output unpredictable results, or it can appear to work normally.

The `-m32` option alters the layout of variables, so that can change what gets stepped on and what doesn't.

Just because a program core dumps sometimes doesn't mean it will core dump all the time.

Post the code, and we can probably identify the source of the UB.

Comment: hi, thanks for the hint.  i just update the question. -m32 does not cause a difference.